# Как исправить WARNINGS: ?: (staticfiles.W004) The directory 'C:\Users\123\web-site\mysite\static' in the STATICFILES_DIRS setting does not exist

Tags: python, django

Я новичок в Django, подскажите, пожалуйста, как исправить эту ошибку:

```
WARNINGS:
?: (staticfiles.W004) The directory 'C:\Users\123\web-site\mysite\static' in the STATICFILES_DIRS setting does not exist.
```

Comment: Ну вроде в тексте ошибки напрямую написано в чём проблема, что непонятно?

Answer (score 0):

Просто создай папку static в папке mysite